# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 0

Tags: java, array

Cuando intento ejecutar este programa simple (adjunto repositorio y cito las partes relevantes) obtengo el siguiente error de tipo 'runtime':

***Input diamond size as an odd integer: 7***

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at DiamondMatrix.<init>(DiamondMatrix.java:26)
        at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Según he investigado, este error se da al intentar acceder a un índice inválido o inexistente de un array, pero en mi caso intento acceder al array `matrix[0][0]`, cuyos índices deberían ser válidos.

El error apunta a la línea 26 del archivo DiamondMatrix.java (la línea 11 del archivo Main no es más que la inicialización de ese objeto). Se encuentra aquí:

```java
//Filling matrix with blanks
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){

            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
                matrix[y][x] = ' ';
            }
        }
```

[Repositorio](https://github.com/pabloasenjo3/Diamond-printer.git)

---

¿Por qué se produce este error? ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Es el siguiente: `char[][] matrix;`

Comment: En realidad el problema es que escribí `matrix = new char[size][size];` antes de `size = diamondSize;`, por lo que `size` estaba indefinido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el orden en cómo declaras tu arreglo.

Este es tu código actual:

```
//Building diamond's 
matrix = new char[size][size];

//Building a field to copy its size
size = diamondSize;
```

Si te das cuenta estás inicializando tu arreglo con `size`, pero ese valor no está disponible hasta después, por lo que debería ser así:

```
//Building a field to copy its size
size = diamondSize;

//Building diamond's 
matrix = new char[size][size];
```

O bien, utilizar `diamondSize` en lugar de `size`.

```
//Building diamond's 
matrix = new char[diamondSize][diamondSize];

//Building a field to copy its size
size = diamondSize;
```